# I was trying the below given code but it showed error CS0051

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

```
namespace Barber_Bazaar.Controllers
{
    public class ScissorsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
        private readonly IScissorsRepository _scissorsRepository;

        public ScissorsController(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IScissorsRepository scissorsRepository)
        {
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
            _scissorsRepository = scissorsRepository;

        }
        public ViewResult List()
        {
            var Scissors = _scissorsRepository.Scissors;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Next  time write a proper question, including an actual question, and what you have tried yourself to fix your situation.

Answer (score 0):

CS0051 is Inconsistent accessibility.

You might want to check on your interfaces and properties and make sure it's set to `public`.